# Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined react checbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm newbie in react. i want to toggle value with checkbox. but i have an error `Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined`. the code is as follows:

```
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'

class JobList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      full_time:false
    }
    this.handleCheckBox = this.handleCheckBox(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

   handleCheckBox(event) {
    this.setState({
      full_time:event.target.checked
    })

  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state.full_time)
    event.preventDefault();

  }

   render() {
    return(
      <div>
       <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       </Form>
        <Form.Check aria-label="option 1" checked={this.state.full_time} onChange={this.handleCheckBox} />

      </div>
    )



}
```

i try using many answer in this forum, but none of them solve my problem. does anyone can help me ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to `bind` this with you function and calling it on constructor of your component.

So when in your `handleCheckBox` you are passing `this` so `this` does not have `target` property so it will return undefined.

```
this.handleCheckBox = this.handleCheckBox(this) // issue is here
```

To solve this `bind` function as below:-

```
this.handleCheckBox = this.handleCheckBox.bind(this)
```

Comment: omg, that's my silly mistake. thank you, you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In React v16 (and older), the `event` object doesn't hang around after the function returns. Remember that React state updates are asynchronous, and so the event object has likely been nullified and returned back to the event pool*. Save the `checked` value *before* enqueueing the state update. You are also missing the `this` binding in the constructor, either fix that or convert to arrow function so `this` of the class is bound automatically.

```
handleCheckBox = (event) => {
  const { checked } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    full_time: checked,
  });
}
```

* Note: This is no longer the case in React v17.

[Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

> Note:
>
> As of v17, `e.persist()` doesn’t do anything because the `SyntheticEvent`
> is no longer [pooled](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html).